In MOOSE I want to pass LineValueSampler from a VectorPostProcessor to a PostProcessor
I want to build a function based on LineValueSampler (VectorPostProcessor) but analysed on a postprocessor in MOOSE. Specifically, from LineValueSampler I get as output [variable][id][x][y][z] in a .csv file for each iteration. My interest is to pass this output from LineValueSampler (VectorPostProcessor) to a PostProcessor in a single .csv. In this PostProcessor I would like to take a specific value of [variable] and then compare it with a threshold. If the difference between
[variable]-threshold < tolerance --> I save this value.

Do you have suggestions to solve this problem? Thank you for your patience. Below there are .h and .C in which I introduce the idea. Can you help me?
neckvalue.h:
#ifndef NECKVALUE_H
#define NECKVALUE_H

#include "GeneralPostprocessor.h"

class neckvalue : public GeneralPostprocessor
{
public:
  neckvalue(const InputParameters & parameters);
  static InputParameters validParams();

  Real calculateValue();

protected:

  std::vector<Real> _c_var;
  const Real _threshold;
  const Real _tolerance;


};

#endif 

neckvalue.cpp:
#include "neckvalue.h"

registerMooseObject("ParrotApp", neckvalue);

InputParameters
neckvalue::validParams()
{
  InputParameters params = GeneralPostprocessor::validParams();
 
    params.addRequiredParam<Real>("threshold", "Seconda variabile");
    params.addRequiredParam<Real>("tolerance", "Terza variabile");
  return params;
}

neckvalue::neckvalue(
  const InputParameters &parameters)
    : GeneralPostprocessor(parameters),
    _threshold(getParam<Real>("threshold")),
    _tolerance(getParam<Real>("tolerance")),
    _c_var(getParam<Real>("c_var"))
{}

Real neckvalue::calculateValue() {

  Real value = 0.0; 
  const VectorPostprocessorValue &values = (getVectorPostprocessorValue("NeckLineValueSampler","value"));
  
  std::vector<double> c_var = values;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    if (std::abs(_c_var[i] - _threshold) < _tolerance)  
    {
      value = c_var[i];
    }
  }
  return value;
}


It should be right now. Thank you for pointing this out to me

ok, now it should be ok
